# get out of memory exception when indexing files with solrj

Tags: solr, solrj, heap-dump

I write a simple program with solrj that index files but after a minute passed it crashed and the 
java.lang.OutOfmemoryError : java heap space appears

I use Eclipse and my memory storage is about 2GB and i set the -Xms1024M-Xmx2048M for both my VM arg of tomcat and my application in Debug Configuration and uncomment the maxBufferedDocs in solrconfig and set it to 100 then run again the application but it crash soon when it reaches the files greater than 500MB

is there any config to index large files with solrj? 
the detail my solrj is as below:

```
String urlString = "http://localhost:8983/solr/file"; 
CommonsHttpSolrServer solr = new CommonsHttpSolrServer(urlString); 

ContentStreamUpdateRequest req = new ContentStreamUpdateRequest("/update/extract"); 

req.addFile(file); 
req.setParam("literal.id", file.getAbsolutePath()); 
req.setParam("literal.name", file.getName()); 
req.setAction(ACTION.COMMIT, true, true); 

solr.request(req);
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you also setting the heap size params when running the java class in eclipse ?

```
Run -> Run Configurations > <Class Name> > Arguments -> VM arguments
```

Comment: yes i set the heap size for java class in eclipse, i also trace the memory usage and i understand every file that solrj indexed the memory is growing up, it seems that solr keep the whole index in memory and do not write into hard space,does it any config to deletion the memory and force it to write into hard?

Comment: seems so ... instead of addFile Try using the stream.file param and the file path. The file reading would be handled by Solr. You need to modify the code using different classes.

Comment: thanks for your help,i change my method and use ModifiableSolrParams and for adding files i used params.set("stream.file",file.getAbsolutePath()) then it works for large video and image files and no heap size exception occurs but when i adding the pdf document the ram is still growing up and after indexing each pdf there is no deletion for it occupation in ram

Answer (score 0):

Is Solr also running on the same machine as solrj? There might be memory constraints on the machine where you are running Solr. How much free memory do you have once you start Solr? - you will probably need more memory available on that box.

Try to put a commit after every document and see if you can get around the problem temporarily.

Comment: i add solr.commit(); but the problem still happen, i think the problem is around this code: req.addFile(file) and solrj does not delete it from memory and because of that, memory is growing up and heap size exception occurs,is there any method to close the ContentStreamUpdateRequest after adding each document?

Comment: Sorry, i am not that familiar with contentstreamupdater and how it works. Is it an option for you to use a different updater?